# Properly coding Email Form with PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, email

So, two problems:

1.) My email form is not working, on submit, it advises "web page can't be displayed".

2.) The email form, when properly coded, did not send an email.

I'm trying to get my email form to properly work. It was working, (however was not sending email) then I rearranged some things (added subject line in the form). Now, I can't seem to figure out what went wonky once I added a subject line. Any suggestions?

https://jsfiddle.net/ebxam743/1/

My PHP form is in the CSS section of JSFIDDLE.

Contact Form HTML

```
<div class="col-md-8">
       <form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">

          <div class="row contact-row">
            <div class="col-md-6 contact-name">

              <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Name">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 contact-email">

              <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail*">
            </div>
          </div>

          <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject*">

          <textarea name="comments" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-color btn-submit" value="Send Message">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
       <!-- end col -->
```

PHP (can't get it to format properly)...

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "you@yourdomain.com";

    $email_subject = "Your email subject line";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please <a href="contact.html">go back</a> and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['subject']) ||

        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

    }



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $telephone = $_POST['subject']; // not required

    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required



    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';


  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'The Message you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string($subject)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->


 <center><img src="img/rebelliouslogob.png" 

             Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.</center>

    <a href="contact.html"><h1>Go Back</h1></a>



<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: Well, how do you expect us to help if you do not post your php code? Please note that a link to some arbitrary site is _not_ a replacement to posting your code inline inside the question. You _have to_ post the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Well I couldn't get it to post without it looking wonky in the code option....

Comment: Then you should sort out how it looks. _Not_ posting it is not an answer to that, is it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not a coder, so I don't know how to format it properly which is why I come here for help.

Comment: Using an embedded editor does not require coding skills, sorry. Stop making excuses, take care to ask your question in a way that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Have a good day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131850/discussion-between-arkascha-and-adr5194).

Comment: Why do you explicitly suppress notices and warnings using the `@` character before your call to the `mail()` function? Those warnings offer very valuable information, you should _never_ suppress them...

Comment: @AndrewLarsen Absolutely. But that is not our business. The OP is expected to know what he is doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so I found 2 errors.

**First error**

This line:

```
echo "Please <a href="contact.html">go back</a> and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
```

Should be changed to:

```
echo "Please <a href=\"contact.html\">go back</a> and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
```

Because the quote symbol is breaking the string, so if you need to use the quote symbol inside a string you need to escape it by adding a backslash or create strings using single quotes.

**Second error**

You are referring to a variable called $subject that doesn't exist.

So instead of using a variable called $telephone which contains the subject data, change the name of it to $subject *(you never use the variable $telephone, so it shouldn't affect you)*.

This line:

```
$telephone = $_POST['subject']; // not required
```

Should be changed to:

```
$subject = $_POST['subject']; // not required
```

**EDIT: Tested the code on my server after the two changes I mentioned above, and I received an email as expected.**

Comment: Thank you for helping! It worked.